# My Activity stops updating some Views that are updated via handler.post or runonuithread

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contentprovider, android-handler

My app consists of

1) An Activity 
2) A service (forground) 
3) A contentProvider... Writes to it inside the service, reads from it (cursor and observer) in the activity

The service maintains a Bluetooth connection to a device that is reporting data about once every second.  The service then writes a tag/value pair to the content provider database.

The activity consists of some textviews, some buttons and some imageviews.  It is also using the SpeedView dials package.  However if I dont use the speedview the problem still happens.

The activity subscribes to the contentprovider for cursor loadercallbacks to init the screen and then uses a contentObserver to listen for changes.

Inside the contentObserver onChange(self,uri) {} .. it will see a change, request the value of the URI and then proceed to try to update the corresponding View.

OK so here is the problem.  Because the callback is as if I think I understand "not" in the main looper, it cannot directly call some of the UI apis directly... For example trying to change the text of a TextView.

In the past this was not a biggie what I simply would do is create a handler and simply do something along these lines...

```
TextView mytextview...
Handler mHandler = null;

onCreate() { ...  mytextview = findviewbyid(...)... 
mHandler = new Handler();// No looper means main thread I think
}

onChange(self,uri) {
....

mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    run() {
       mytextview.setText("the new text from the content provider");
      }
 });
  .....
}
```

So what is the problem? Well at first nothing.. This works.. Well at least for several minutes.  Not totally predictable sometimes quick sometimes after about 15 minutes .. But eventually the handler.post() wont work anymore.  I placed a Log before the handler.post and a log inside the run() at the start and finish... I always see the log finish and the GUI update but then for some reason I wont see any logs except the one prior to the handler.post (meaning the content provider callback is still working!)

I am a bit at wits end as to why this will run for several minutes and simply stop. Its like some sort of internal looper queue is filling up.

My other attempts to use handeler.post(runnable)) to change a text view or other views didn't have these issues (at least maybe I didn't see them if the activity wasn't showing that long or for some other reason??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this isnt a true answer to the solution.. However what I discovered is that my updates from the Observer calling the handler.post was about at a rate of 50ms.

thats a bit fast though it still doesnt explain why no crashing or errors.

My workaround that seems to be working is instead of using an Observer update to call the handler.post that updates the UI is to do a crude POLLING of the observer class and poll at 100ms.  Using a handler.postDelayed() and inside there doing the updates to the UI by checking the observer class for changes (polling) of each variable to see if any of them changed and if so then update the UI.